# User security stamp for Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-identity

I have a Multitenant MVC5 application which lets tenants specify their authentication & authorisation method. They can choose between local account which uses ASPIdentity behind the scenes or using their Active directory logins which uses LDAP.

The ASP identity stuff has a security guid against the user which is wrapped up in the [IUserSecurityStampStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613277%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

For those that don't know, this guid is essentially a snapshot of the users details. If you modify users details you can update this guid which would log the user out.

My question

Is there anything like the security guid for Active Directory? I need a way of tracking whether a user's details have been modified since they've been logged in. This doesnt essentially need to be a guid stamp it could be a datetime stamp.

Comment: I think you can try using date of last modification http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/01/06/how-can-i-tell-on-what-date-an-active-directory-user-account-was-created.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the scenario you are trying to solve. 
You want a "..way of tracking whether a user's details have been modified since they've been logged in"

Probably the best method is to read the either:
whenChanged
or 
modifyTimeStamp

of an entry when the entry performs the logon.

Then check to see if the value has changes since the logon.

I have some doubts that this will be enough as there are some values that could change when performing the logon.

I can think of these that might change and there could be more (depending on your configuration and customization of AD:
badPasswordTime
lastLogoff
lastLogon
lastLogonTimestamp
lockoutTime
logonCount
pwdLastSet

-jim

Comment: whenChanged is marked as not-replicated attribute in Active Directory. modifyTimeStamp is marked as constructed attribute (effectively an alias for whenChanged) Source: http://blog.joeware.net/2006/10/03/655/ This will require the application to query all DCs in the domain for most recent value when comparing the attribute and security stamp